# Movie Clip Keeps Appearing Behind

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two movie clips called mc_England and mc_Scotland they are on separate layers but placed on the stage in the same position.

When I click the close button on one of the clips I can't tell which close button I'm clicking.

If I move the two movie clips onto different parts of the stage the code below works correctly.

I'm probably missing something simple but I cant see what?

Any help would be great.

UPDATE:

As the Close button being in the same position was causing the problem.

I decided to set the position of each Movie clip to come on and off stage.

This works apart from the FinishTween not completing before re positioning the movie clip.

Is there a way to set the position after a tween has completed?

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

//Buttons Open
btn_England_Open.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, England_Open);
btn_Scotland_Open.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Scotland_Open);


//Button Close
mc_England.btn_England_Close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, England_Close);
mc_Scotland.btn_Scotland_Close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Scotland_Close);


//Open Functions
function England_Open(e:MouseEvent){
    StartTween(mc_England);
}
function Scotland_Open(e:MouseEvent){
    StartTween(mc_Scotland);
}

//Close Function
function England_Close(e:MouseEvent){
    FinishTween(mc_England);
}
function Scotland_Close(e:MouseEvent){
    FinishTween(mc_Scotland);
}


//Tween Function
useSeconds);
function StartTween(target:MovieClip){
    target.x = 386.90;
    target.y = 195.00;
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(target, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 1, 0.5, true);
    //myTween.start();
}

//Tween Function
function FinishTween(target:MovieClip){
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(target, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 0.5, true);
    //myTween.start();
    target.x = -100;
    target.y = -100;
}
```

Comment: Can u explain the movieclip structure so we can better understand the situation?

Comment: Within each of my Movie Clip mc_England and mc_Scotland there is a close button btn_England_Close and btn_Scotland_Close. I think the problem is that the close buttons are at the same position on stage. As the alpha is set to 0 I'm not actually clicking the close button I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

What specifically do you mean by "breaks" the FinishTween function?

Are the close buttons in the same location as well?  I would take a look to confirm that the object you expect to be dispatching the MouseEvent is really the one doing it.  Even if the close button is tweened to 0 alpha, it is still listening for MouseEvents if it's area is clicked on.

Comment: Your right I'm not clicking the close button I'm seeing on screen due to the alpha being set to 0 at start.

Is it possible to disable all other Button and Movie Clips when a specific Movie Clip is open?

Comment: One option to accomplish that would be something like:
`//Open Functions
function England_Open(e:MouseEvent){
 btn_England_Open.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, England_Open);
                  mc_England.btn_England_Close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, England_Close);
    StartTween(mc_England);
`
That way, you don't start to listen for events until the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is that when you click the close button of one clip you get both FinishTweens started (the only one i can imagine after reading the question):

```
function England_Close(e:MouseEvent){
    e.stopPropagation();
    FinishTween(mc_England);
}
function Scotland_Close(e:MouseEvent){
    e.stopPropagation();
    FinishTween(mc_Scotland);
}
```

or else i need more details

Comment: I don't think there would be issues with both buttons getting click events because one of them always has to be in front of the other. Nothing in the code suggests that one of the movieclips is a parent of the other so stopping propagation probably won't help